# Convergence behaviour for a fixed point iteration

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, solution-verification, fixed-point-theorems

I'm trying to show the following properties for the fixed point iteration $$x_{k+1} = \phi(x_k)$$
used to find the zero $\alpha$ of $f(x)$

> if $\phi'(\alpha) \in (0,1)$, the convergence is monotone, i.e. $x^k - \alpha$ has the same sign for every $k$.
>
> if $\phi'(\alpha) \in (-1,0)$, the convergence is oscillating, i.e. the error $x^k - \alpha$ changes sign varying $k$

---

Here's my attempt:

I know that $$x_{k+1} - \alpha = \phi(x_k)- \phi(\alpha) = \phi'(\xi_k) (x_k - \alpha)$$ for $\xi_k$ between $x_k$ and $\alpha$.

Now, since $|\phi'(\alpha)|<1$, then we know that there exists a $\delta >0$ s.t. for every initial data $x_0$ in $(\alpha - \delta, \alpha+\delta) = I$ we have that $\{ x_k\}_k$ converges to $\alpha$.

- If $\phi'(\alpha) \in (0,1)$, since $$e_{k+1} \approx \phi'(\alpha) e_k$$ (I'm assuming that $\phi'$ does not change a lot in $I$) I have that $\{ e_k \}_k$ decrease but the sign is always the same.
- If $\phi'(\alpha) \in (-1,0)$, then from $$e_{k+1} \approx (\phi'(\alpha))^k e_0$$ I have that for $k$ even the error is positive, while for $k$ odd it is negative (I assumed WLOG $e_0>0$). Of course, as $|\phi'|<1 $ in $I$, I have that the magnitude of $e_k$ decreases. So the plot "$e_k$ vs iteration $k$" will be a sort of zig-zag  (where the zig and zag has differen signs (lol)) converging to $0$ as $k$ grows.

**Essentially**, my argument relies on the  fact that $\phi'(\alpha) \approx \phi(x)$ for $x \in I$, i.e. that in the neighbourhood $I$ the derivative does not vary much.

Is my procedure correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some minor adjustments to your argument:

It is likely a typo, but you should have

$$x_{k+1}-\alpha=\phi(x_k)-\phi(\alpha)=\phi\color{red}'(\xi_k)(x_k-\alpha)$$

$$e_{k+1}=\phi'(\xi_k)e_k$$

One should then note that

- If $\phi'(\alpha)>0$, then $\phi'(\xi)>0$ for all $\xi$ in a neighborhood of $\alpha$. Likewise for $\phi'(\alpha)<0$.

From this can conclude that as long as $x_k$ is sufficiently close to $\alpha$, then

- If $\phi'(\alpha)>0$, then the sign of $e_{k+1}$ is the same $e_k$ (monotone).
- If $\phi'(\alpha)<0$, then the sign of $e_{k+1}$ is the opposite of $e_k$ (oscillating).

Comment: Yes, I forgot the derivative, thanks. Your argument is clear, now I'm not so sure about mine. I mean, I am doing the strong assumption $\phi'(\alpha) \approx \phi'(\xi)$ for $\xi $ in  a neigbourhood of $\alpha$, right? @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: You can actually use what you have, since $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{e_{k+1}}{e_k}=\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(\alpha)}{x-\alpha}=\phi'(\alpha)$$ so that if $x_k\to\alpha$ then $\phi'(\xi_k)\to\phi'(\alpha)$. I'm just providing a weaker statement that also works here.

Comment: Okay it's clear :) Btw, I have similar question, if you want to answer it's here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806268/prove-newton-iterates-converge-to-0-for-x-01