# Prove Newton iterates converge to $0$ for $|x_0|<1$

Tags: numerical-methods, solution-verification, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson, fixed-points

I need a check on the following exercise, since I don't have the solution

> Let $g \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $g(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$. Show that  Newton iterates for the equation $g'(x)=0$ satisfy: $$|x_0|<1 \Longrightarrow g(x_{k+1})<g(x_k)$$  and > $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_k = 0$$

---

Here's my attempt:

First I write the Newton iterates for $g'(x)=0$, which is $$x_{k+1}=\frac{x_k^3}{1+2x_k^2}$$ Now, I note that $\frac{x_k^2}{1+2x^2} \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ for every $x_k$. Therefore, if I take an initial data $|x_0|<1$, then $|x_1|<1$ as well. Generalizing, every time I multiply for a number less than $\frac{1}{2}$ a number less than $1$, therefore this sequence is monotone.

- If $x_0 \in (0,1)$, I have that such a sequence bounded from below by $0$ and it's decreasing, hence $\lim_k x_k=0$
- On the other hand, if $x_0 \in (-1,0)$, then the sequence is bounded  from above by $0$ and it's increasing. Therefore $\lim_k x_k = 0$.

Since $x \mapsto g(x)$ is increasing for $x \in (0,+\infty)$ and decreasing in $(-\infty,0)$, I have that:

- If $x_0 \in (-1,0)$ ( i.e $\{ x_k \}_k$ increasing and lives in $(-1,0)$): $x_{k+1} > x_k$, but if I apply $g$ (which is decreasing): $g(x_{k+1})<g(x_k)$
- If $x_0 \in (0,1)$, (i.e. $x\{ x_k \}$ decreasing): $g(x_{k+1})<g(x_k)$  since $g$ here preserves the monotonicity.

---

Hope it's everything fine.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Only nitpick is you might want to make an argument as to why you can't have $\lim x_k$ be non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for the check, I'd say that the sequence is monotone and bounded (the first time from below, the second from above) by $0$, and hence the limit must be zero. Or should I use something else? @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: Being monotone and bounded above (below) by zero only guarantees the limit exists and is at most (least) zero, not that it has to be zero.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt But the sequence is strictly monotone, so it is zero. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This doesn't guarantee the limit can't be something like $\pm0.01$ for example.

Comment: Uhm, then I don't know what I am missing, honestly. @SimplyBeautifulArt could you give me an hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks fine to me. Only nitpick is you might want to make an argument as to why you can't have $\lim x_k$ be non-zero.

The key is noting that $|x_{k+1}|\le|x_k|/2$ so that $|x_k|\le|x_0|/2^k$. From this, what can you conclude?

Comment: Well, by the squeeze theorem and the fact that $|x_0|<1$, I have that $|x_k| \rightarrow 0$ . Thanks :)